Difficulties reading from Modbus device
I am using a RS485 to USB module to connect a thermocouple module to my computer. I installed a CH340 driver and the device appears in the device manager.
I ordered the RS485 to USB module of Amazon and only have very limited instructions how to read the information from the thermocouple.
The communication happens via Modbus. I got the communication configuration from the product site, but am not having success with getting any readings using pymodbus. This is the code I am using.
from pymodbus.client import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient 

client = ModbusClient(
    method='rtu',  # bitsize = 8 -> likely rtu 
    port='COM4',   
    baudrate=9600, -> data sheet 
    parity='N', -> check digit = none
    stopbits=1, -> data sheet
    bytesize=8, -> data sheet 
    timeout=5 -> guessing 
)

# Connect to the Modbus server
client.connect()

# Modbus configuration
device_address = 1 -> device address = 1 from data sheet
register_address = 0 -> register address = 0x01 from data sheet 
number_of_reads = 1 -> data sheet

# Read the holding registers
response = client.read_holding_registers(register_address, number_of_reads, unit=device_address)

# Check if the read was successful
if response.isError():
    print(client.connected)
    print(f"Error reading from Modbus device: {response}")
else:
    # Extract and process the temperature value
    register_value = response.registers[0]  # Get the first register value
    temperature = register_value / 10.0  # Convert to temperature
    print(f"Temperature: {temperature:.1f} °C")

However I don't get any readouts. I only receive the following error message:
Error reading from Modbus device: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] No response received, expected at least 4 bytes (0 received)

Does anybody have an idea what I might be doing wrong in my approach with pymodbus?
Thanks!

Can you provide the module model?

Of the RS485 to USB module? It's this one: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08Y8WXZMM?psc=1&ref=product_details

Your code looks OK (note that V3 uses slave rather than unit); you might find it easier to test with a tool like mbpoll/Modpoll). My guess would cabling issue (the info on the amazon page is pretty incomplete, suspect it was copied from here) or hardware issue (but there may also be driver issues e.g.).

It seems that you must send a command for module. Amazon product description  says "Read command: 0X03".
As K-Type Thermocouplemodule uses a MAX6675, I suggest you the following websites:
a) https://randomnerdtutorials.com/arduino-k-type-thermocouple-max6675/
b) https://github.com/adafruit/MAX6675-library/tree/master
c) https://github.com/archemius/MAX6675-Raspberry-pi-python/blob/master/max6675.py
In these sites, it seems the value is readed only after sending a command to module.
Unfortunately, I don't have necessary hardware to test and help you further.
